# Adding table column dividers without distorting column data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

Is there an easy way to create vertical dividers between HTML table columns? I want to add thick bars, but the only good way I've seen to do this is to distort table data add TD's.

Is there a way to add vertical dividers between columns of a table using only jQuery+CSS?

My table structure is pretty simple.

```
<table>
<thead><tr><th>...</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr>...</tr>...</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: td { border-right: 3px solid black}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you are searching for is a attribute for the  tag and it is called rules:
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/_TABLE_RULES.html

```
<table rules="cols">
  <thead><tr><th>...</tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr>...</tr>...</tbody>
</table>
```

You can style it using the css border properties. But the advantage over using a border on every cell is the fact that it will not add a border at the right side of the table (or the last cell actually) so you don't have to add a special class to the last cell to overwrite the border.

**EDIT:** Add the attribute border="0" to the  tag if you don't want a border around the whole table (or not left/right of the first/last column).

EXAMPLE: http://jsbin.com/ixire

Comment: It looks like colgroup + rules might be what I'm looking for. I'll test all this out.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the styling of border that "rules" produces?

Comment: You can style the colgroup to affect the rules.

Comment: this attribute is not supported by HTML5, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_rules.asp

Answer (score 3):

Using the cell border is one option you can use but there's another:

I'm not sure if you can change your table structure but if you can, use the [colgroup](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-colgroup-element) and col tags for table. I did a quick test in latest of FF, Chrome and Opera and it worked in all:

```
  <style type="text/css">
     table {
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        border-collapse:collapse;
     }

     .col {
        border-right:10px solid blue;
     }

  </style>

  <div id="tDiv">

  <table border="1">
     <colgroup class="col">
        <col width="200" />
     </colgroup>
     <colgroup class="col">
        <col width="200" />
     </colgroup>
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>one</th>
           <th>two</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>one one</td>
           <td>one two</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>   
  </table>
</div>
```

I did not get a change to test in IE (any versions of it) though.

Comment: I just tested it in ie6, no luck :(, Might work if you add html5.js

Comment: I don't need to support IE6 :). customer accepted being forced to IE7+.

Comment: This doesn't work fully, but it works with rules, presented below.

Answer (score 1):

Generally done with border on the right (or left) of each cell.

This -> http://jsfiddle.net/XFtBR/ should give you a start point.

Comment: I tried td borders, but cell padding made the vertical lines disconnect.